# Independentsoft generate html email

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm using Independentsoft MSG to generate an .msg file.  How do i set the format of the .msg file to HTML instead of plain text.

```
Message message = new Message();
message.Subject = "Test";
message.Body = "Body text";
message.MessageFlags.Add(MessageFlag.Unsent);
message.StoreSupportMasks.Add(StoreSupportMask.Create);
message.Save("c:\\temp\\message.msg", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

From their tutorial seems pretty easy 
http://www.independentsoft.de/msg/tutorial/createhtmlmessage.html